# Parallelize the execution of a function that has multiple params

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that I want to run in parallel for different params.
The function creates a hash file for tables in a snowflake database.
I want to run it for 2 different databases in Snowflake.

The args of the function are:

```
> Args:
>         df_hash (pandas.DataFrame): DataFrame containing the table and hash query.
>         conn: The connection object to the Snowflake database.
>         output_folder (str): The folder to save the hash files.
```

I want to be able to run this function as follows:

```
    # parallelized the file processing loop using multiprocessing for potential speed improvements
    with Pool(processes) as pool:
        pool.map(create_hash_file(df_fivetran_hash_generate, fivetran_conn, output_folder_fivetran), fivetran_chunks)
        pool.map(create_hash_file(df_datalake_hash_generate, datalake_conn, output_folder_dynamics), datalake_chunks)
    pool.join()
```

But I get an exception on the map function :
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

After doing some research I found that map does not take more than one param for the function passed to it. Some were suggesting the use of starmap, but I've tried doing:

```
    with Pool(processes) as pool:
        args = zip(fivetran_conn,output_folder_fivetran)
        pool.starmap(create_hash_file(df_fivetran_hash_generate, args), fivetran_chunks)
        args = zip(datalake_conn,output_folder_dynamics)
        pool.starmap(create_hash_file(df_datalake_hash_generate, args), datalake_chunks)
    pool.join()
```

But it didn't work.. and I don't think I understand well how the map vs starmap functions operate.
Any guidance is appreciated!